# Issue with MUI datagrid and dropdown component: Selected row always shows the last row

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, datagrid

`I am junior developer, its first time I want to customize and use the MUI datagrid in deeply way and I have the following issue:
I am facing an issue with the Material-UI (MUI) datagrid and a dropdown component I have implemented. In my datagrid, I have action buttons in each row, and when I click on them, the selected row always shows as the last row, even though the console logs the correct clicked row data. However, when I remove the dropdown component and directly access the params, it works correctly.

Here is the relevant code snippet:

```
const Index = () => {
 
  const [anchorEl2, setAnchorEl2] = useState(null);
 
 
  const [selectedRow, setSelectedRow] = useState(null);



  const handleOpen = () => {
    setAddOpen(true);
  };

  const handleClick2Index = (event) => {
    setAnchorEl2(event.currentTarget);
  };

  const handleEdit = (params) => {
    console.log(params);
    setEditOpen(true);
    setSelectedRow({ name: params?.row?.name, description: params?.row?.description });
    setAnchorEl2(null);
  };
  const handleDelete = (params) => {
    console.log(params);
    setDeleteOpen(true);
    setSelectedRow({ name: params?.row?.name, description: params?.row?.description });
    setAnchorEl2(null);
  };

  const columns = [
    {
      field: 'name',
      headerName: 'Name',
      width: 200,
    },
    {
      field: 'description',
      headerName: 'Description',
      width: 200,
    },
    {
      field: 'action',
      headerName: 'Action',
      width: 100,
      renderCell: (params) => (
        <div>
          <button
            sx={{ width: '4', height: '4', borderRadius: '100%' }}
            onClick={handleClick2Index}
          >
            <IconDots />
          </button>
          {/* it is a dropdown(the issue) */}
          <Dropdown anchorEl2={anchorEl2} params={params} setAnchorEl2={setAnchorEl2}>
            {/* key error */}
            <ListItem onClick={() => handleEdit(params)}>
              <ListItemIcon>
                <IconEdit width={20} />
              </ListItemIcon>
              <ListItemText>Update</ListItemText>
            </ListItem>
            <ListItem onClick={() => handleDelete(params)}>
              <ListItemIcon>
                <IconTrash width={20} />
              </ListItemIcon>
              <ListItemText>Delete</ListItemText>
            </ListItem>
          </Dropdown>
        </div>
      ),
    },
  ];

  if (isFetching) return <Loader />;
  return (
    <PageContainer title="Categories" subtitle="Page">
      {addOpen && <AddCategory onOpen={addOpen} setOnOpen={setAddOpen} />}
      {editOpen && <EditCategory onOpen={editOpen} setOnOpen={setEditOpen} data={selectedRow} />}
      <DashboardCard
        headtitle="Categories List"
        title="Categories Management"
        subtitle="Page"
        cardheading="true"
        action={
          <Button
            variant="button"
            sx={{
```

```
          backgroundColor: 'primary.main',
          color: 'white',
          ':hover': { backgroundColor: 'primary.light', color: 'black' },
        }}
        onClick={handleOpen}
      >
        Add New
      </Button>
    }
  >
    <StyledMUIDataGrid data={data} columns={columns} />
  </DashboardCard>
</PageContainer>
```

);
};

```
export default Index;
```

[I am selecting action buttons of the first row](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gkOOw.png)
[but it shows the data of the last row](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jt6Wg.png)
I suspect that the issue might be related to how I am using the params in the Dropdown component. The params parameter I being used to get the value of the current row, but it seems to be retaining the value of the last row clicked instead of the current row.

I have tried logging the `params` object, and it correctly shows the data for the clicked row. However, when I pass the params to the `handleEdit` or `handleDelete` functions, the `selectedRow` state variable is always set as the last row, not the current one.

I have also noticed that if I remove the dropdown component and directly access the params, everything works as expected.

Can someone help me identify the issue and suggest a solution? I believe the problem lies in how I am using the prams, but I'm not sure how to fix it.

Thank you in advance for your assistance.